# Android: build.properties exclude

Tags: android, ant, build

I'm wondering whether it is possible to exclude several source files from a folder included with `src.dir = ...` in build.properties

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write like this:

```
<fileset dir="${src.dir}">
    <exclude name="your-file-name-or-pattern"/>
    <include name="your-file-name-or-pattern"/>
</fileset>
```

The name attribute accepts both the file name and a pattern that matches multiple files.

For more detailed information about this, see:
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html

When you read this page, pay attention to  and selectors too.

Comment: But this is Android - the android tools generate my build.xml file, and I have no control over the javac task. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @noamtm Actually I don't know the structure of android sdk generated ant build file...However it should use Ant's javac task, and, as long as it uses Ant's javac task, you can modify the parts according to Ant's javac task manual http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html

Comment: I know this is an old question, but could somebody elaborate how to achieve this with the android build system? I want to selectively include/exclude certain java files from the build depending on a condition. The base build.xml file that is provided by the sdk has a javac rule with <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" /> How do we make it exclude files?